# React/Redux - Rest operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this state:

```
const initialState = {
  selectedGroup: {},
  groups: {
    rows: [],
    total: null
  },
  offset: 0,
  range: 15,
  loading: false,
  error: null
}
```

In a reducer, i have:

```
case Types.SUCCESS_LOAD_GROUPS:
   return {
      ...state,
      loading: false,
      groups: {
        total: action.groups.count,
        rows: [ ...state.groups.rows, action.groups.rows ]
      }
    }
```

What i want to do is insert all data received in `action.groups.rows` into `groups.rows`, keeping old values. But it is creating two arrays instead of putting all together, example:

[image]

Value of `'action.groups.rows'`

[image]

Comment: spread the second rows array like so -> rows: [ ...state.groups.rows, ...action.groups.rows ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a spread operator on both the arrays inside a new array would be an appropriate way of updating the rows.

`rows: [ ...state.groups.rows, ...action.groups.rows ]`

Comment: It works, Thanks!!  3 dots on state means that it will keep old values, but 3 dots on action, what it does? Works but i cant understand why hahauahua

Comment: The `...` is a syntax referred to as spread operator. It was introduced in ES6. It is a useful and quick syntax for adding items to arrays, combining arrays or objects, Here is a useful article to develop more understanding about it. https://dev.to/torianne02/breaking-down-es6-spread-operator-k1m

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried concatenating the arrays for example, in your reducer:

```
rows: state.groups.rows.concat(action.groups.rows)
```